# .net Core - Make the package version the same as the assembly version

Tags: .net-core

How can I automate making the package version the same as my assembly version after a successful build?

[image]

Comment: By typing the Assembly version into the Package Version field?  Note that, if you want automation, you need to say so.

Comment: after updating this, just clean and re-build the project to get it reflected or delete obj and bin folder and re-build depending on the dev environment you are using.